# How to use Docker to run various web servers on default ports on one server?

Tags: java, python, django, wordpress, nginx

My goal is to have web servers that work on the default port so users don't have to type in a port #.  Easy to do with LAMP stack, where A is apache... and no other web server exists.  However, if I purchase general purpose hosting with Centos and I want to run 
1) Gunicorn/NGINX for Python/Django -> access from example.com from outside (no port required to be entered by the web browser.
2) Spring framework in a Java EE container - Java EE defaults to port 8080 and other ports in that range but people just enter a domain name and expect it to work.  -> So reachable from example2.com
3) Node.js - Reachable from example3.com
4) PHP apps such as WordPress, Drupal on LAMP - example3.com

Recommendations are appreciated.
My closest experience that seems to do this for example would be AWS with load balancer allowing access from public web - app servers accessible from only load balancer.

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: yes, a proxy/load-balancer is what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nearly any http server in front to do this kind of job.

bind everything (tomcat, nodejs, gunicorn, uwsgi, etc. pp.) to local http or file sockets and use the proxy feature of your favorite server to bundle them all on this host. With the naming of nginx: use different *locations* on one *server* and/or different *server blocks* with proper *server names* set to build your custom host.

A few servers:

- **nginx** with [proxy feature](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)
- **apache2** supports setups like that, too if you use [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).
- **haproxy** [is another alternative](http://www.haproxy.org/)

Finally it depends on your specific needs (and experiences) which setup to pick.

**Edit:** missed docker a little - but the same thing works for containers - except that you do not use file sockets, but make everything with (http) sockets in private or public nets.

Comment: I was wondering if I could get more details.  So, nginx or apache2 with mod_proxy would serve as a load balancer ( that was how it was described for a best practice on AWS - according to the course author ).  Anyway, so, the proxy out front listens on the default port for web pages - port 80.  Somehow, it redirects to the correct server or docker container, depending on type of app ( J2EE, NodeJS, gunicorn or uwisgi for python web apps)?  How can I learn more about this - proxy servers, directing requests to the appropriate server type?

Comment: Basically, I was asking for advice on where to learn more...  books, training online, etc.